# jquery autocomplete input name = json_decode data name

Tags: jquery, json

How can I automatically insert into jQuery the value data I get from the database using json_encode where json data = input name?

how can i automatically stick a value for input in jquery with the same name attribute as the gain via php json_encode?

for example, please keep in mind that I have several dozen inputs on a page with a different name attribute:

from json encode it gives me, for example, documentnumber and I want to automatically paste it on input with the same name attribute.

if the input has another name attribute, then the value with the same name obtained from json is automatically filled in the value

Comment: You know what would make this make sense.... code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be best to take the Tour first. For this question, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data like:

```
var data = [{
  "Ks":  "KS 1",
  "Endtext":  "End Text 1",
  "fZlava": "FZ Lava 1",
  "Cena": "Cena 1",
  "FDPH": "FDPH 1",
  "FSPOLI":  "FSPOLI 1"
}];
```

This would be an array of objects. So calling `data[0].Ks` will return the value `KS 1`. You can also get the Object Key names `Object.keys(data[0])` which will return an array.

You can use the `name` attribute selector to select specific elements.

```
$("input[name='Ks']")
```

Consider the following example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "action/update/edit.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {id: id, action: action},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    var keys;
    $.each(data, function(i, o){
      keys = Object.keys(o);
      $.each(keys, function(j, k){
        $("input[name='" + k + "']").val(o[k]);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

This will populate a text field with the corresponding `name` attribute. This is fine and all unless you have many with the same name.

```js
$(function() {
  function getData(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        var keys;
        $.each(data, function(i, o) {
          keys = Object.keys(o);
          $.each(keys, function(j, k) {
            $("input[name='" + k + "']").val(o[k]);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
  getData("https://jsonblob.com/api/b0d9708d-079a-11eb-903e-cb8263972736");
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li label {
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><label>KS</label><input type="text" name="Ks" /></li>
    <li><label>ET</label><input type="text" name="Endtext" /></li>
    <li><label>FZ</label><input type="text" name="fZlava" /></li>
    <li><label>CN</label><input type="text" name="Cena" /></li>
    <li><label>FD</label><input type="text" name="FDPH" /></li>
    <li><label>FS</label><input type="text" name="FSPOLI" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IN PHP 
  <?php
  foreach ($result as $row) {
  $output['Ks'] =  $row['bks'];
  $output['Endtext'] =  $row['textend'];
  $output['fZlava'] =  $row['sspolu'];
  $output['Cena'] =  $row['cspolu'];
  $output['FDPH'] =  $row['dspolu'];
  $output['FSPOLI'] =  $row['uhrada'];
  }
  echo json_encode($output);
  }
```

I need to automatically assign a value for value in jQuery based on data coming from $ output ['name']

something like this

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "action/update/edit.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {id: id, action: action},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('input[name]').val(data.output);
         }
    });
```

where input name equals $output value

Comment: it is better question ?

Comment: Still need an example of the data and an example of the Inputs.